How do I change the text in a row to yellow if the text in a specific cell in specific columns match on both sheets?
Let me elaborate. I made a post before asking something similar. In that question, I asked how to delete duplicates if they matches on both sheets in excel. However, now I need to figure out how to change the entire text of a row into yellow if specific rows on sheet 2 matches with specific rows on sheet 1. Also, how to only have the code run through what is being shown such as a list that is filtered (this is important as the excel sheet is very big so if the code ran through the entire sheet and not just the filtered part, it would take an extremely long time).
Here is an example:
Sheet 1  Sheet 2  looks like this. (I apologize for the screenshots I do not know how to insert actual text like this into here I am very new) As you can see, sheet 1 and sheet 2 have the same info, but the columns are not in the correct order. I need to code to run through sheet 2 on column D and B and if the columns E and F on sheet 1 (respectively) match, then the whole row's text color will be changed to yellow. Of course, pretend like these lists were filtered down to this size so the code will only scan over what is filtered and not the whole sheet.
This is the code I have currently:
Sub HighlightDuplicates()
    
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, r As Long
    Dim dups As Object, k As String, rngDel As Range, rw As Range
    
    Set rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Set rng2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    
    Set dups = RowKeyCount(rng2.Offset(1).Resize(rng2.Rows.Count - 1))
    
    
    For r = 2 To rng1.Rows.Count
        Set rw = rng1.Rows(r)
        k = RowKey(rw)
        If Len(k) > 0 And dups.Exists(k) Then
            BuildRange rngDel, rw
            dups(k) = dups(k) - 1
            If dups(k) = 0 Then dups.Remove k
        End If
    Next r
    
   
    If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.Font.Color = vbYellow 'or delete
    End Sub 
    Function RowKeyCount(rng As Range) As Object
    Dim rw As Range, k As String, dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each rw In rng.Rows
        k = RowKey(rw)
        If Len(k) > 0 Then dict(k) = dict(k) + 1
    Next rw
    Set RowKeyCount = dict
 End Function


Function RowKey(rw As Range) As String
    If Application.CountA(rw) > 0 Then
        RowKey = rw.Worksheet.Evaluate("=TextJoin(""|"",FALSE," & rw.Address & ")")
    End If
 End Function

 Sub BuildRange(ByRef rngTot As Range, rngAdd As Range)
    If rngTot Is Nothing Then
        Set rngTot = rngAdd
    Else
        Set rngTot = Application.Union(rngTot, rngAdd)
    End If
 End Sub

My issue is that I don't know how to only run the code through the filtered area and I have no idea how to call specific columns across multiple sheets to check if they are the same. Currently, the code runs through the whole sheet, not just the filtered part, and it requires each row to be exactly the same in order to highlight the whole row.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

as the excel sheet is very big - How many rows <10k, <100k , >500k ?

There is 1 row on Sheet 2 with KLPO 11/19/2024  and 3 matches to that key on Sheet1.  Which rows need to be highlighted , is it all of them ?

Is this following the same rules as your previous post?  If there's only one entry on sheet2 then only highlight one matching entry on sheet1?  Might both sheets be filtered, or only sheet1?

@CDP1802 Only one of them should be highlighted. If there are 3 of a kind on sheet 1 and 2 of the same on sheet 2, then only 2 will be highlighted on sheet 1.

@TimWilliams Both sheets might be filtered. Assume all the same rules as the old post unless it conflicts. In that case, the guidelines in this post take precedence.

A change to the RowKey function to add an optional parts parameter takes care of most of your changes.
Visible rows only can be managed with SpecialCells()
Sub DeleteDups()
    
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, r As Long
    Dim dups As Object, k As String, rngDel As Range, rw As Range
    
    'visible rows only from sheet1
    Set rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Set rng2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Set rng2 = rng2.Offset(1).Resize(rng2.Rows.count - 1) 'excluding headers
    
    Set dups = RowKeyCount(rng2, Array(5, 6))
    rng1.Font.Color = vbBlack 'reset any highlighting
    
    For Each rw In rng1.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows
        If rw.Row > 1 Then
            k = RowKey(rw, Array(4, 2))
            If Len(k) > 0 And dups.Exists(k) Then
                BuildRange rngDel, rw   'flag for deletion
                dups(k) = dups(k) - 1   'decrement count remaining
                If dups(k) = 0 Then dups.Remove k 'all dups handled?
            End If
        End If 'row>1
    Next rw
    
    'any duplicates found?
    If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.Font.Color = vbRed 'or delete...
    
End Sub

'Return a dictionary of "row key" (concatenated from all values
'  in each row of `rng`) mapped to the count of each key's occurence
'Optionally specify `parts` as a relative range address to key only specific columns
Function RowKeyCount(rng As Range, Optional parts As Variant) As Object
    Dim rw As Range, k As String, dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each rw In rng.Rows
        k = RowKey(rw, parts)
        If Len(k) > 0 Then dict(k) = dict(k) + 1
    Next rw
    Set RowKeyCount = dict
End Function

'If rw is not empty, concatenate values with "|"
'All values are used, unless `parts` is supplied (as an array of
'  column indexes to be used to form the key)
Function RowKey(rw As Range, Optional parts As Variant) As String
    Dim addr As String
    If Application.CountA(rw) > 0 Then
        If Not IsMissing(parts) Then
            Debug.Print rw.Address(), Join(parts, ",") 'for debugging
            RowKey = Join(Application.Index(rw, parts), "|")
        Else
            RowKey = rw.Worksheet.Evaluate("=TextJoin(""|"",FALSE," & rw.Address & ")")
        End If
    End If
End Function

'build up a range in steps
Sub BuildRange(ByRef rngTot As Range, rngAdd As Range)
    If rngTot Is Nothing Then
        Set rngTot = rngAdd
    Else
        Set rngTot = Application.Union(rngTot, rngAdd)
    End If
End Sub


RowKey = Join(Application.Index(rw, parts), "|") is not working for some reason. I am getting runtime error 13 type mismatch notification.

Do you have any hidden columns in your data?

When it fails what is rw.Address() and what is parts ?

I'm so sorry for the late reply. I do not have any hidden columns. I don't know how to check the rw.address() or the parts.

When it fails click "Debug", put ? rw.address() in the Immediate window and press Enter.   Same for ? Join(parts, ",")   Or you can add Debug.Print rw.Address(), Join(parts, ",") to the RowKey function as shown in my edit above.

It says, "Method not valid without suitable object" Did I place the code in the wrong function?

Sorry I had that Debug.Print in the wrong place.  Fixed above.

The code has no errors anymore! However, whenever I run the code, nothing happens. I wanted to see if the color reset even works so I changed the color of one of the words in a cell and ran the code and the code didn't even reset the color back to black. I wonder if something is called wrong on it.

It works for me - there's really no way for me to know what's the problem with your actual data unless you're willing to share a sample workbook.

I am making a new post soon. The sheet I will run this on will be small enough to run on without filtering and the columns compared are going to be columns G and F on sheets 1 and 2 and columns K and B on sheets 1 and 2 respectively. I apologize for so many iterations of this code, but this will be the final iteration. The person who gave me this task was extremely vague. If the code keeps having problem, I absolutely have no problem sharing a workbook with you. Thank you for your help!

The code I posted here will need no changes for that, other than removing the SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) for the loop over rng1 (even if you left it in there wouldn't be any problem though...)  You just need to make sure you pass the correct array as the argument to RowKey parts

I see. I posted the post and used an old code that does work, if you want to look at it. I'll also share a workbook with you if you'd like.

The email is sent.
